# FREE NEWS API VIA GITHUB, How to implement this code in retrofit?

Tags: api, android-studio, retrofit, retrofit2, free

I came across an amazing **FREE News Api on GitHub** but I don't know how to implement it in retrofit

[SauravKanchan/NEWSAPI](https://github.com/SauravKanchan/NewsAPI)

This API is the cracked version of NEWSAPI with the same functionality, I just want to know how to implement the code in retrofit

API Documentation

BASE_URL = "https://saurav.tech/NewsAPI/"

top_headlines_api = "<BASE_URL>/top-headlines/category//<country_code>.json"

everything_api = "<BASE_URL>/everything/<source_id>.json"

in the above documentation I am confused on how to pass **<county_code>.json** in the retrofit client, help, please!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I figured out how to implement above in retrofit 2

use the below code in your retrofit request INTERFACE in my case its GetNewsByCountry.java

```
   public interface GetNewsByCountry {

    @GET("top-headlines/category/general/{country}.json")
    Call<NEWSPOJO> getAllNews(@Path("country") String country);
}
```

now In your retrofit client instance write the following code

```
public class RetrofitClientInstance {

    public static final String BASE_URL = "https://saurav.tech/NewsAPI/";
    private static Retrofit retrofit = null;
    public static Retrofit getRetrofitInstance() {
        if (retrofit==null) {
            retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .build();
}
        return retrofit;
    }
}
```

Note I have created different classes,i.e. GetNewsByCountry, java and RetrofitClientInstance.java for the above code

and to finally make an HTTP call write the below code in your activity/fragment class

```
GetNewsByCountry service = RetrofitClientInstance.getRetrofitInstance()
.create(GetNewsByCountry.class);
                Call<YOUR_POJO_CLASS> call = service.getAllNews("us");
                call.enqueue(new Callback<YOUR_POJO_CLASS>() {

                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(Call<YOUR_POJO_CLASS> call, Response<YOUR_POJO_CLASS> response) {

                           /** TODO: implement the logic you want when you receive the
JSON data, most probably you want to show 
the result in recycler view so I am pasting 
my code here, u know just in case
    
     Log.v("onResponse", "we are in th on response callback");
    
                            assert response.body() != null;
                            List<Article> list = response.body().getArticles();
                            adapter = new NewsAdapter(getActivity(), list);
    
                            recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
                            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    */
    
    
                        }
    
    
    
                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(Call<NEWSPOJO> call, Throwable t) {
                           /** progressDialog.dismiss();
                            Log.e("“out”", t.toString());
    
                            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Something went wrong...Please try later!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    */
                        }
    
                    });
```

comment if u have any doubt left!